# Unable to use LMB in any properties to increase or decrease values

Tags: interface, properties

**Blender version 2.90.1 on a Mac (version 10.15.6) using a Magic Mouse**

In any properties view I am unable to use LMB and drag to increase or decrease values. I tried to find anything in preferences related to this function but unable to find anything. I did reset preferences and the function still doesn't work.

It would be a great help if you can provide guidance on how to resolve this issue.